# Performance issues with big texture sizes

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

In my project I am using 5 layers of very wide images, that are on top of each other and cover the whole screen.
In total these images are made out of 20 textures (4 per layer) with 512x512 pixels in size.

I use the PVRTC format to load and compress those textures to save memory. I checked with Instruments and internal memory on devices is not an issue due to the compression but I only get around 10-15fps if I enable and draw all layers.
If I only draw one layer (4 textures) for example I get an ok framerate of around 55fps.

I strongly suspect that my textures are simply too big and cause a bottleneck while rendering. I am not sure however how to counter and solve this bottleneck.

I would be very grateful for any advice and tips on how to handle such big images/textures correctly to get good performance.

Comment: Have you tried using smaller textures? Maybe the problem is something else. It seems like you are drawing lots of very big quads. Maybe [this is the problem](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/advanced/advanced97/notes/node211.html).

Comment: It seems like you are right. If I make the ViewPort smaller performance goes up quite significantly. What is this telling me, how can I get the same performance while rendering to full screen?

Comment: Are you enabling blending for this scene? That can really slow down compositing of these images. If possible, draw all the opaque elements first with blending off, then only the elements that need blending. You might even be able to apply a custom shader to speed up some of this.